# HTML::Template Perl

Tags: html, json, perl

IIs there a package similar to HTml::Template in perl which takes a JSON object and maps it to a HTML template file? I am building a web application using HTML::Template and will be receiving JSOn from a web services API, things will be made simple if I can templatize this JSOn to HTML instead of doing it the exact way HTML::Template requires.

Answer (score 6):

HTML::Template just takes a data structure consisting of strings, hashes and arrays. JSON maps directly onto that.

```
$template->param(myData => JSON::Any->new->decode($json_string));
```

Comment: OK, what would the HTML template code look like if I want to print a deep attribute of a JSON object?

Comment: Look at the [loop section of the docs](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Template#TMPL_LOOP)

Comment: This works for a simple 1 or 2 level JSON object, however using TMPL_LOOP is sub-optimal for complex JSON data structures. It leads to cumbersome and ugly HTML template code. I was looking for something where I could do <TMPL_VAR NAME="user.address.street"> and access a JSON object for that user that contains the user's address then street directly. It requires me to know the JSON object's structure, but that I know.

Answer (score 1):

`HTML::Template` is a rather 'simple' templating engine - I am using quotes because its simplicity let's you do whatever you need in a `view` part from the `Model View Controller` architecture.

However, you can not execute arbitrary perl code inside a `HTML::Template`.

Also, due to the fact that in `JSON` you could have very complex data structures, I doubt that there are any suitable ways of using `JSON` in a straight way in your templates.

The only solution I see as possible is for you to use a Perl script that will parse the `JSON`, create some 'objects' and pass them to your templates. You already have that perl script - is the one that instantiate your `HTML::Template` object.

Answer (score 1):

ok, a bit late, but:
HTML::Template always wants a hash of arrays of hashes and so on.
and you cannot navigate through the parameter stash.
If you want to do this, you might try out HTML::Template::Compiled which allows you to do this.

```
<tmpl_var some_hash.key.another_key[23] >
```

or with alternative delimiters:

```
[%= some_hash.key.another_key[23] %]
```

but note the documented differences of the module to HTML::Template.

So you decode your JSON string to a data structure and pass it to the template and then you can access all values somewhere deep in the structure.